# i can't insert any data from workbench tool

Tags: php, sql, mysql-workbench

When I insert the data from my application of even though by workbench the database don't insert anything and it also gives me the message to tell me that the data was inserted successfully but nothing is inserted. Is the grant privileges was responsible for that of what? Can anyone tell me why?

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES ('test', 3, 'some text');
```

Comment: That would suggest that you are looking incorrectly at the table, need to commit the transaction, or perhaps that there is a trigger.  A permissions issue would be obvious.  It would say that you don't have permissions.

Comment: no i look for the correct table , because manually from workbench tool also doesn't work , and also i grant all privileges to the user that i worked with but also i can't insert  anything

Comment: @GordonLinoff any ideas ?